# clickonce deployement strategy update for specific users for beta testing

Tags: winforms, clickonce

Question is plain and simple:

I want to publish my latest version to selected users for beta testing. Is there any quick and dirty way to do the same.

Here is the link that I found in MSDN which is bit old and suggesting an approach but I dont think i need to put this much effort. Rather I will just use a different installer for beta testing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480721.aspx[^]

Comment: What about just using a different publish URL and site?

Comment: Thanks Ghost. Yes I have that in my mind. Just was trying to find any quick and easy approach for the same. I just don't want to give multiple installers to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a new site with a different publish URL. It is the most manageable option I can think of. Users connect to that site and download the beta version and could run it in parallel with another version for comparison purposes.

You are going to have two versions of the client application so you are going to have two installers; I don't think you can get around that. Having multiple publish URLs means people don't have to uninstall/re-install the app to get the "right version".

Embrace MAGE and script it out.